# Starting off with OpenGL under Cygwin

Tags: opengl, cygwin

Is it possible to compile and run OpenGL programs from under Cygwin? If yes, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is possible to compile and run OpenGL programs under Cygwin. I illustrate the basic steps here:

1. I assume you know OpenGL programming. If not, get the [Red Book](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/) (*The OpenGL Programming Guide*). It is mandatory reading for OpenGL anyway.
2. I assume you have Cygwin installed. If not, visit [cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com/) and install it.
3. To compile and run OpenGL programs, you need the Cygwin package named **opengl**. In the Cygwin installer, it can be found under the *Graphics section*. Please install this package.
4. Write a simple OpenGL program, say *ogl.c*.
5. Compile the program using the flags **-lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32**. (This links your program with the GLUT, GLU and OpenGL libraries. An OpenGL program might typically use functions from all the 3 of them.) For example:

   > $ gcc ogl.c -lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32
6. Run the program. It's as simple as that!

Comment: Currently, there is no package *opengl* in the Cygwin repositories.

Comment: Currently, there is neither `opengl` nor `freeglut` in Cygwin afaik.

Comment: Humm, might it be down as `gl` rather than `opengl`?  If you are using `CMake` as a project system `cygwin` does make use of `pkg-config` which can help with finding libraries but it is a little confusing for OpenGL...!

Comment: The OpenGL packages in Cygwin are named `libGL-devel` and `libGL1`. There are also a lot of other extensions https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html

Answer (score 3):

If the above doesn't work (and it didn't for me), try the following (which did!)

gcc ogl.c -lglut -lglu -lgl

Answer (score 3):

I do not normally post answers this long, but this one is worth it.

I will present a **Windows 10 64-bit** setup for **Cygwin** that uses *the same libraries* as **Visual Studio**. You will be able to use both development environments with the same code (same includes and libraries), so you can switch between the two as you see fit.

You need three libraries: **OpenGL**, **GLEW**, and **GLFW**.

1. *OpenGL*

**Visual Studio:** The following default locations are valid for current versions of Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2019.

OpenGL static library:

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\SDK\ScopeCPPSDK\vc15\lib\SDK\lib\opengl32.lib
```

OpenGL DLL:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll
```

The `opengl32.lib` library will need to be specified under the VS project `Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`. The same applies for all other dynamic libraries under Visual Studio. I will not mention it again.

**Cygwin:**

OpenGL static library default location:

```
/lib/w32api/libopengl32.a
```

OpenGL dynamic library (uses the Windows DLL):

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll
```

2. *GLEW*

**Visual Studio:** Download 32-bit/64-bit binaries from `http://glew.sourceforge.net/` and install in a custom folder, say `C:\OpenGL\glew-2.1.0`. The same download works for both Visual Studio and Cygwin.

GLEW headers (to `#include GL/glew.h`):

```
C:\OpenGL\glew-2.1.0\include
```

GLEW static library:

```
C:\OpenGL\glew-2.1.0\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib
```

GLEW DLL:

```
C:\OpenGL\glew-2.1.0\bin\Release\x64\glew32.dll
```

These can be specified in your VS project's Properties menu.

**Cygwin:** You can link against this library from Cygwin as-is, meaning you can specify its download directory for the `INCS`, `LIBS`, and `LDLIBS` variables in your `Makefile` as follows (consistent with the download directory specified above):

GLEW headers directory:

```
/cygdrive/c/OpenGL/glew-2.1.0/include
```

GLEW static library directory:

```
/cygdrive/c/OpenGL/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/x64
```

GLEW dynamic library directory:

```
/cygdrive/c/OpenGL/glew-2.1.0/bin/Release/x64
```

With these values for `INCS`, `LIBS`, and `LDLIBS` respectively, you can then link using the UNIX naming conventions as shown in the complete `Makefile`, at the bottom of the post.

3. *GLFW*

This can be downloaded at `https://www.glfw.org/download`. For our 64-bit setup, you need the Windows 64-bit precompiled binaries. You can place it also in a custom folder, say `C:\OpenGL\glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64`. The same download works for both VS and Cygwin.

**Visual Studio:**
You can specify directly the download locations into your project Properties for headers (to `#include GLFW/glfw3.h` in your source code) and DLLs (to have VS link against these libraries), respectively.

**Cygwin:**
For Cygwin, GLFW is trickier, because you can no longer link against it directly from the download location. You need to:

(a) copy the headers, static, and dynamic libraries from the download locations:

```
C:\OpenGL\glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64\include\GLFW\*.h
C:\OpenGL\glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64\*.a
C:\OpenGL\glfw-3.3.4.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64\*.dll
```

...into your toolchain's (MinGW's) respective locations:

GLFW headers (create the `include` directory):

```
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GLFW/*.h
```

GLFW static libraries:

```
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/*.a
```

GLFW dynamic libraries:

```
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/*.dll
```

(b) place the dynamic library location into your PATH environment variable, editable in your `.bash_profile` file in your home directory.

The `Makefile` for Cygwin is:

```
CC=/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-c++.exe
OPTS=-std=c++11
DEBUG=-g
CFLAGS=-Wall -c ${DEBUG}

INCS=  -I.\
       -I/cygdrive/c/OpenGL/glew-2.1.0/include\
       -I/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32

LIBS=   -L/usr/lib\
        -L/cygdrive/c/OpenGL/glew-2.1.0/lib/Release/x64\
        -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib

LDLIBS= -L/bin\
        -L/cygdrive/c/OpenGL/glew-2.1.0/bin/Release/x64\
        -L/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin

Program.o:  Program.cpp
            ${CC} ${OPTS} ${INCS} -c $<

Program:    Program.o
            ${CC} ${OPTS} ${LIBS} ${LDLIBS} Program.o -lopengl32 -lglew32 -lglew32.dll -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -luser32 -o Program
```

With this setup, you can use the same exact source code files in both VS and Cygwin. You can compile, link, and run `Program.exe` from its directory in Cygwin with:

```
$ make Program
$ ./Program.exe
```

You can run from VS a Cygwin-compiled program by opening the existing `*.exe` as an SLN project and running it using the IDE interface. Conversely, you can run the VS executable (created by VS in `Project/Debug` or `Project/Release`) directly from the Cygwin command line with the command above.

The includes are:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

No changes whatsoever will have to be made in the source code to switch back and forth b/w VS and Cygwin. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

I remember doing this once with some success, a few years ago, basically trying to cross compile a small Linux OpenGL C++ program. I do recall problems with Windows OpenGL drivers being behind the times (due to MS's focus on DirectX). I had NVidia OpenGL and DirectX drivers installed on my Windows system, but cygwin/g++ seemed to want to only use the Microsoft OpenGL DLLs, many years old, which do not have the latest support for all the ARB extensions, like shader programs, etc. YMMV.