# G++ openGL application under Cygwin

Tags: opengl, g++, cygwin

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344/starting-off-with-opengl-under-cygwin), but it did not help. Builder returns me this:

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Itun/workspace/VoxEngine/Debug/../src/main.cpp:30: undefined reference to _glEnable
/cygdrive/c/Users/Itun/workspace/VoxEngine/Debug/../src/main.cpp:31: undefined reference to _glClearColor'`.
```

What do `-lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32` flags mean? Where are the libs?

How to create OpenGL project under Cygwin with Eclipse?

**UPDATE**:
I add -I/usr/include/opengl to g++ and it starts to work. In this folder there is a single file GL.dll. How does this dll influence to the compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag **-l** `-lglut32 -lglu32 -lopengl32` tell the linker to link against libraries *libglut32*, *libglu32* and *libopengl32*

However your error indicated you didn't include any OpenGL header files. (`#include <GL/gl.h>`, `#include <GL/glu.h>`)

Cygwin keeps to the Unix way and places libraries in `$CYGWINPREFIX/usr/lib` and includes in `$CYGWINPREFIX/usr/include`.

Comment: I use #include <GL/gl.h>, #include <GL/glu.h>. I have not opengl libs in $CYGWINPREFIX/usr/lib, but I have them in $CYGWINPREFIX/lib/w32api

Comment: @itun: that location should be in order, as under Windows OpenGL libraries require some extra caretaking. However it probably becomes neccesary yo add this to the linker's search path: `-L$CYGWINPREFIX/lib/w32api`

Comment: It does not help, this is the linker invoking: g++ -L"C:\cygwin\lib\w32api" -o"VoxEngine.exe"  ./src/main.o   -lopengl32 -lglu32

Comment: That definitely is NOT the compile error (undeclared symbol) you'd get from omitting a header file.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Depends on the compiler and the language profile selected. If you'd use pure ANSI-C (not the case here), then not including a header file will cause implicit symbols. Similar is possible with GCC / g++ in certain configurations, though unlikely. Also depending on the compiler/headers there might be #pragma for linkage there, as well.

Comment: @datenwolf: Under ANSI C, you'd get warnings instead of errors, but not the error shown.  In ANSI C, names aren't mangled based on parameter types, so implicit symbols wouldn't cause undefined reference errors.  Missing `#define`s (that rename the function) might I guess.  But the filenames clearly indicate we aren't dealing with C.